# Why popen opened file is empty?

Tags: c, linux

Trying to get output of an `strace` command with c i wrote this code slice:

```
int main()
{
    FILE* pout;
    pout = popen("strace -fp 44030 2>&1 | grep write","r");

    char buff[1000];
    int d1,d2;
    while(1){
        if(fgets(buff,1000,pout)!=NULL)
        {
            printf("buff=%s\n",buff);
        }
        else
            continue;
    }
    pclose(pout);
}
```

When i run the stated command in shell i see some output (the 44030 process is a `top` command running in another terminal). BUT i see nothing when running my program.
Moreover when i substitute the command in `popen` with  `"strace -fp 44030 2>&1"` i see output of strace command by running my program. and I've checked for problems in `grep` and `popen` with another piece of code replacing the strace with an `echo` command. 
Where is my problem? where can i look for my error?
EDIT:
As i waited for some time now there is lots of output there... I Think this is happening because of some kind of buffering in grep command.

Comment: You could check the return value from `popen()` for a start.

Comment: Not sure if relevant, but your `else continue;` is redundant, and your loop will loop forever in any case. Did you mean `else break;`?

Comment: @squeamishossifrage you are right...Actually  I've checked for that in my main code.. but when removing extra code for simplicity i forgot to copy that part here...

Comment: Is there a positive result for `grep` when you run in shell?

Comment: @Prabhu yes... it prints an stream of lines

Comment: Cannot reproduce this.

Comment: @n.m. I edited the question and i think i should delete it cause the problem was with grep buffering... i should find a realtime grep option..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to disable buffering in grep, which you can do using `unbuffer`.  See here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe

Comment: I'm working on an embedded linux project and there is no unbuffer available there. I searched and found --line-buffered option for grep which is also not available with provided grep... so i think i should crosscompile unbuffer or a full version of grep... is there another way? + How should i use unbuffer in my command?(is popen("unbuffer...","r") sufficient?)

Comment: @mhk if you have to build something, easier will be `stdbuf`: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/25378/14502